# Gscam cannot find plugins

Tags: ros, gscam, pandaboard, image-transport, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i am trying to run gscam to send images using webcam and pandaboard.
I have succesfyllu installed ros groovy robot distribution on pandaboard using ubuntu 12.10. When i try to run gscam i get this message:

```
stream is PAUSED.
[ INFO] [1367231465.122704640]: Successfully read camera calibration.  Rerun camera calibrator if it is incorrect.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'image_transport::Exception'
  what():  No plugins found! Does `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin image_transport` find any packages?
Aborted
```

When I try to run `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin image_transport`, I get:

```
compressed_image_transport /root/robot_ws/image_transport_plugins/compressed_image_transport/compressed_plugins.xml
compressed_depth_image_transport /root/robot_ws/image_transport_plugins/compressed_depth_image_transport/compressed_depth_plugins.xml
theora_image_transport /root/robot_ws/image_transport_plugins/theora_image_transport/theora_plugins.xml
image_transport /root/robot_ws/image_common/image_transport/default_plugins.xml
```

The list of available transports looks like this:

```
Declared transports:
image_transport/compressed (*): Not available. Try 'rosmake compressed_image_transport'.
image_transport/compressedDepth (*): Not available. Try 'rosmake compressed_depth_image_transport'.
image_transport/raw (*): Not available. Try 'rosmake image_transport'.
image_transport/theora (*): Not available. Try 'rosmake theora_image_transport'.
```

Running `rosmake` on plugins completes succesfully, bet the list of transports still say they are not built. Is it possible I am missing some PATH variables linking to compiled plugins? Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61735/gscam-cannot-find-plugins/) by [rokas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4784/rokas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The image_transport_plugins stack is catkinized (it has a package.xml instead of the older manifest.xml); you should add it to your catkin workspace and build it with catkin.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rokas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4784/rokas/) on 2013-04-30**:
I just found that it's possible to download it using apt-get from Ros for arm sources and now it seems to start, but still can't get image on a remote host `/gscam/image_raw` topic appears in the topic list, but the image is empty..

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-04-30**:
That's probably the topic for a new question.